# Composition of two linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T_1 : \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $T_2 : \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3} \to \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ are linear transformation, where $T_2(A) = A^T$. If $ A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i  \end{bmatrix}$ 
and ($T_1 \circ T_2)(A) = T_1(A)$.

Find $T_1(A)$

What I'm doing is to write

$\begin{align}
(T_1 \circ T_2)(A) &= T_1(T_2(A)) \\
T_1 (A)&= T_1(A^T)
\end{align}$.

From this result I'm sure that I can't say $A=A^T$. Because I have no infomation that $T_1$ is injective.  But $T_1$ has to be a linear transformation that brings every matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. What I have to do next?

Comment: Have you forgotten? $T_1$ is into $\Bbb R^2$, not $\Bbb R^{3\times 3}$. However, your confusion on how to solve it is understandable. The problem is underspecified. There are plenty of linear maps that are invariant under transpose. 3 simple examples would be $$T_1(A) = \begin{bmatrix}a\\e\end{bmatrix}\\T_1(A) = \begin{bmatrix}e\\i\end{bmatrix}\\T_1(A) = \begin{bmatrix}i\\a\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Pardon me.. It was a misstyped. It's into $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: There are many possibilities for $T_1(A)$. Do you have any other conditions, or are you trying to find the general solution?

Comment: Ther's no other condition. May I know how can $T_1$ has many possibilities?. And what is the general solution to this?

Comment: $T_1(A) = a, T_1(A) = e, T_1(A) = i, T_1(A) = b+d, T_1(A) = c + g, T_1(A) = f+h$, and any linear combination of those all satisfy the condition.